# HMS: After integration of Account kit getting error code : 6004

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

We have integrated Account kit for our project and while verifying the functionality, we have encountered error code : 6004. We have already tried to **re-enable the account kit service in AGC and also cleared HMS core cache**, but still facing same error.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please verify below check points:

1. Ensure that you have [enabled Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickgame-enable-account-kit-0000001159772367) , if already enabled please disable it and then re-enable it. Please wait for 15 minutes, and clear the HMS Core cache of the test phone, and then retry.

> Please follow below mentioned procedure for clearing cache :
>
> To clear the HMS cache data, go to Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core >
> Storage, and tap Clear cache. To clear the HMS management space, go to
> Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core > Storage, tap MANAGE SPACE and then
> CLEAR DATA

2. Please verify whether App id present in agconnect-services.json in your app directory(App_name -- > App -– >  agconnect-services.json) is same as App Id present in AppGallery connect. Please refer to [Obtaining the App ID](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickgame-create-quickgame-0000001159652387#section6839048331).
3. Ensure that the [fingerprint certificate](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickgame-generate-fingerprint-0000001113452452#section1451505553914) used by the APK is the same as that entered when you [enable Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickgame-enable-account-kit-0000001159772367#section16741825133511).

Please check the above check points and try again. Hope you resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot there was issue related to fingerprint certificate, issue got fixed after re-verifying it.